# Can I create a base model for two existing models

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and I have a question on models. My code references two views from a SQL Server database. The first returns all records while the second returns only a subset. Since there are two views there are two models: qryAll and qrySome. But the records returned from each view are the same so the two models are the same.

What I want is to write code that doesn't care which one it gets (qry) since they are really the same. It won't seem to let me put a new class in the Models directory.

Update: I added a base class in the Models folder with the right namespace and sub-classed the existing models. It compiles, but throws a "The entity type  is not part of the model for the current context."

Comment: can you provide some sample methods you have written and where its failing

Comment: It isn't failing, I just have two methods for each task: link to the view, read from the view, process the results from the view. Lots of duplicated code because of the duplicated models.

Comment: What do you mean by "It won't seem to let me put a new class in the Models directory."

Comment: It wouldn't let me put a new class in the xxModel.tt file / folder which is where the existing model cs files are and where I was trying to add my base class. I could add the new class in the Models folder and then sub-class the existing models.

Comment: What version of EF?  You don't need any inheritence for this scenario.  You have one Entity type and a second method that hits the `qrySome` view and returns an IEnumerable or IQueryable of the same Entity type.

Answer (score -2):

create Base Class and extend  derived class

Comment: They are in a "Models" folder that appears to be untouchable.

Comment: The xxModel.tt file contains the two models and can not be added to. The Models folder can be added to. I created a new base class and extended the existing models.